# iOS 8 "Copy/Paste" Dialogue Disappears

Tags: ios, iphone, safari

Currently working on a web app which has many input fields. Everything works great across devices except for iOS 8.

**When I go to select text and then hold my press down for copy/paste the dialogue appears but then quickly disappears before I can copy or paste the text. It's important that the user can paste into the input, has anyone else run into this issue and found a solution?**

I've surfed the web with the iPhone 6 and found that it happens across some websites but not on others so I'm wondering if there is a fix for this issue? Happens on all iOS 8 devices but not on iOS 7 or iOS 6. I've tried updating from 8.0 to 8.2 yet it didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out iOS 8 closes their popups every time anything on the site animates in CSS... Taking out this transition fixed everything (since it was happening every 1 second infinitely):

```
body {
    -webkit-animation: drawer infinite 1s;
    -moz-animation: drawer infinite 1s;
    -o-animation: drawer infinite 1s;
    animation: drawer infinite 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes drawer {
    from {
        padding: 0;
    }
    to {
        padding: 0;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes drawer {
    from {
        padding: 0;
    }
    to {
        padding: 0;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes drawer {
    from {
        padding: 0;
    }
    to {
        padding: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes drawer {
    from {
        padding: 0;
    }
    to {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you link to where you found documentation of iOS 8 responding to CSS animations. I am having the same problem, and would like to be able to use animations

Comment: @gr8scott06 -> I never ended up finding a documentation for it, had to eliminate code chunk by chunk until I found the source of the issue..

After taking it out I noticed that other animations are causing the same problem for the copy/paste pop-up but since they don't happen as often as the one I took out it's pretty manageable. (example: carousel running every 6 seconds gives the user 6 second windows to copy/paste... still not ideal but at least it's possible now haha)